# Authorizing Basic authentication fails for rest calls using javascript in php

Tags: php, javascript, rest, basic-authentication

API calls from javascript fails and from PHP curl they are fine.

PHP Script to check authentication

---

```
 if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Test auth"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo '{"status":"401","message":"Unauthorized"}';
        exit;
    } else {
        $user= $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
        $pass =  $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
    }
```

### Javascript // fails

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var apiid = 'admin';
var apipassword = '123';
var requesturl = 'http://localhost/man/api/man/GetLanguages';
xhr.open('POST', requesturl, false, apiid, apipassword);
xhr.send('{}');
if(xhr.status == 200){
     alert(xhr.responseText);
}
```

### PHP curl call

```
$ch = curl_init($url);                                                                
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data),'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIz'));     
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: How exactly does it fail?  What's the error reported?  It's probably a cross-domain security thing.

Comment: i dont see any thing displayed while accessing with javascript call, but for php curl it returning data.

Comment: I have tried this code that accepts cross domain requests.
Added this code in htaccess
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

But with no luck

Comment: Have you find a solution to this issue?